# What weapon talent tree combination provides the highest dps with the flail and shield?

Tags: new-world

New World has a new expansion, and with it, a new weapon. I've been having a lot of fun with it and am still playing around with combinations.

With most of the other weapons in the game, I've had good success using the skills and passives in one tree combined with some passives in the other tree, but with the flail, I haven't been able to really tell if my changes have made much of a DPS difference (I've gone down the Cleric tree mostly rather than the Bastion tree).

So that brings me back to the question in the title - What weapon talent tree combination provides the highest dps with the flail and shield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of what I've found, the highest damaging talent trees with flail and shield build are of the Brawler and Protector.

The Brawler tree provides a lot of damage-boosting talents, such as Crowd Crusher, which increases damage to stunned or staggered enemies, and Maelstrom, which increases attack speed and damage dealt after hitting multiple enemies with a single ability.

While the Protector tree provides some damage-boosting talents, such as Warding Blow, which increases damage dealt after blocking an attack, and Shield Bash, which deals damage and stuns enemies.

I've listed some with high DPS:

**Brawler**

- Crowd Crusher
- Maelstrom
- Wrecking Ball
- Mighty Swing
- Brawler's Grace

**Protector**

- Warding Blow
- Shield Bash
- Shirking Fort
- Reinforced Fortification
- Defender's Resolve